# As a bar owner, how can I block guest from using specific programs, like Spotify, over my free wifi?

Tags: router, wireless-networking

When guests log in to their Spotify account over the wifi, the bar gets thrown out. I would like to have in place a setup where I could still use Spotify, but have it blocked for our guests.
We use a standard wireless router from our telephone provider (Telefonica), the brand is "Comtrend" (Unfortunately I'm pretty blank when it comes to access hardware and such).
Suggestions?

Comment: All of this can be done yes but we'd need to know what existing router-type equipment you already have first.

Comment: @Hurragutt Whereabouts in Spain are you? I only ask, as I'm visiting Barcelona this week :)

Comment: Down south in Cadiz, but Barcelona rocks too!

Answer (score 21):

**To solve this problem as a bar owner:** 
Hire an IT professional

**To solve this problem as an IT professional:** 
Set up your edge device to block traffic to certain domains and IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks WesleyDavid, that was really helpful. More quality answers like that and Joel Spolsky should have nothing to worry about.

Comment: +1 An answer befitting an of-topic question. @Hurragutt, last time I checked bar owners didn't fit the profile of an IT professional. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: I suspect it would have got a less favourable answer on SU.

Answer (score 5):

How much control do you have over your WiFi / LAN settings?  Is it a combined WiFi router, or is it just an access point?

Some WiFi routers have built-in firewalling.  If you can block the great unwashed from accessing 78.31.8.0/22 then you'll block off Spotify's IP range.  You can exempt yourself from the block by giving your computers static IPs that aren't blocked by this rule.

Comment: It's a simple Comtrends router, provided by Telefonica (I'm in Spain), but I should be able to block the range you mention. Thanks! Do you think OpenDNS.org could do the trick as well?

Comment: I have no experience with OpenDNS, but if they allow you to block lookups for Spotify, then that could work.

Comment: Using OpenDNS will only work for PCs that are using OpenDNS for their DNS servers. Since you are dealing with random PCs connecting to your network and have no control of their DNS settings, OpenDNS will not help.

Comment: @KJ-SRS: The vast majority of those random PCs are going to use the DNS servers they get from DHCP, so he/she does have control over those DNS settings.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapo comtrends that telefonica most probably supplies to its customers cannot do what you want.

If you are serious then pop down to your local tech store or browse amazon and get a new device. Most of the ones you have to buy have what you need which is basically filter the incoming and outgoing traffic.

Comment: I agree with this run Pfsense

Comment: I second pfSense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with spotify but I'd venture to guess that it uses standard web-browsing ports to tunnel traffic. Unless you want to invest in a next-generation firewall that is application aware like a Palo Alto Networks or even the latest Sonicwall, there is usually a way around.

You could try other methods, blocking by DNS entry...

What kind of firewall is in place today?